How to add jar file to Lambda conatiner image
I have a jar file which exceeds 50mb and therefore looking to move the jar file to a Lambda container image. I'd like to achieve this without having to recompile the Java app.
As such, I've tried using the below Dockerfile script:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:21
COPY HelloWorld-1.0.jar ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "com.example.myapp.App::handleRequest" ]

However running into the following error message:
Class not found: com.example.myapp.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myapp.App
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

Is it possible to achieve this, or do I have to follow the steps outlined here to create a Lambda container image?
For reference, I created a simple java function using sam init and following the prompts and created a jar file from that, which successfully runs when uploading to Lambda using the Java runtime.
I'm trying to port this directly over to a container image, however seems like this is not possible?

Are you sure you want a 50mb+ Lambda?  What all does your application do that it is that large?  If it is meant to be a quick call you'll be disappointed in the performance.  If it's a long running process (i.e. multiple minutes) then you may be ok.  Again, what all is this Lambda including?
